# hide component of facelet template ui:include ?

Tags: jsf, components, hide, facelets, uiinclude

how can I hide a facelets component I am including in a template?

in my template.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="mainForm">    
<div style="overflow:hidden; width:1020px; height:565px; overflow-x:hidden; " >
        <ui:include src="menuSharepoint.xhtml" styleClass="hide" />     
    <ui:insert name="body">Default Body</ui:insert>
</div>
<div style="width: 1000px; height: 6px; float: left"></div>
</h:form>
```

I'm trying to hide the ui:include menuSharepoint.xhtml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can surround it with a component with a controllable `rendered` property:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="false">
  <ui:include src="menuSharepoint.xhtml"/>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Also rendered can be set as an EL expression like `rendered="#{myBean.menuVisible}"`.

Comment: I tried it but get an error message :  The element type h:form must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</h:form>".  Strange message since the end tag is there.

Comment: There must be something wrong with your xml, analyze it closely. By the way, styleClass is not a valid attribute for ui:include. Also have a look at menuSharepoint.xhtml.

Comment: Remove the `/` from the first tag in this answer.